# JPanel and JScrollPane with only vertical scroll

Tags: java, swing

I'm interested in create a container that receive buttons dynamically. When it reaches the container width the buttons are put in bellow the first line of buttons and a vertical scrollbar must to be showed. Although it can't show the horizontal scrollbar, the container could be resizable horizontally. As an example:
[image]

Clicking on jbutton1 you add new buttons according with panel size. In this picture it's not possible to see the vertical scrollbar and this is the problem.

The code I used is the bellow one:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ScrollPanelTest;

import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

/**
 *
 * @author leandro.lima
 */
public class ScrollPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public int count = 1;
    private WrapLayout layout = new WrapLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5);

    /**
     * Creates new form ScrollPane
     */
    public ScrollPane() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        java.awt.FlowLayout flowLayout1 = new java.awt.FlowLayout();
        flowLayout1.setAlignOnBaseline(true);
        jPanel1.setLayout(flowLayout1);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(327, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(163, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        final JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        button.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        button.setAction(new AbstractAction("<html><center><h4>Button " + (count++) + "</h4><br>Remove me</center></html>") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                jPanel1.remove(button);
                jPanel1.getRootPane().repaint();
                getContentPane().repaint();
            }
        });
        
        jPanel1.add(button);
        jPanel1.getRootPane().repaint();
        getContentPane().repaint();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {

        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ScrollPane().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Obs: I couldn't find a way to repaint the panel when buttons are add, if you know, please show me too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    jPanel1.setLayout(flowLayout1);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);
```

You are using a FlowLayout in the panel. A FlowLayout does NOT recalculate the preferred size of a panel. Since the preferred size never changes, the vertical scrollbar will never appear.

That is why you need to use the `WrapLayout` on your panel.

You define a `WrapLayout` variable but you never actually use the `WrapLayout` on the panel.

Also, I have no idea why you are using a GroupLayout for something so simple. The default layout manager for a frame is a BorderLayout. Just create the scrollpane with the panel and add the scrollpane to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Then you add the other panel containing the button to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. Its two lines of code. Learn you to create your own GUI's and don't rely on the complex code generate by the IDE.

> I couldn't find a way to repaint the panel when buttons are add, if you know, please show me too.

When you add (or remove) components from a visible GUI then the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```